# Specify SVN destination folder name in Buildbot

Tags: linux, svn, buildbot

I'm setting up buildbot to build a project. The project's code is stored in SVN and it uses a couple of libs in our SVN repository.
When performing a manul build, what I need to do is (of course) to checkout the main project and the libs. The command used to checkout the libs is something like:

```
svn co svn://<path_to_lib_repo>/trunk mylib
```

That way the code of the library is stored in a local folder called "*mylib*" where the makefiles will look for.
Is there a way to configure the SVN build step to have the code checked-out to a folder with a custom name, as above? I did not found a way so far.

As a (temporarly?) workaround on Linux, I'm using the **ShellCommand()** step building myself the svn command, but I really don't like such solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the workdir paraemter to set the directory where you want the files. For example:

```
f.addStep(SVN(name='pull.src', repourl=svn://<path_to_lib_repo>/trunk,
              workdir='mylib',
              description='pull.src'))
```